# Check validity and apply style when user leaves the field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html form somthing like this:

```
<form id="contactForm">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required minlength="3" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am using html validations as my requirements are simple. And I want to display input box in red color if user has entered invalid value. I tried using css pseudo classes `valid` and `invalid` like this:

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The problem with this is that all input fields show up in red even when the user has not touched the field. To prevent this issue I am using on blur event in javascript.

```
const contactForm = document.forms.contactForm;
const nameInp = contactForm.name;

nameInp.onblur = function () {
  if (this.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("valid");
  } else {
    console.error("invalid");
  }
};
```

Is it possible to achieve this functionality without javascript using only pseudo classes? I do not want the input boxes to display on red until user clicks on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `:placeholder-shown`, the input needs to have a placeholder

```js
const contactForm = document.forms.contactForm;
const nameInp = contactForm.name;

nameInp.onblur = function () {
  this.removeAttribute('placeholder');
  if (this.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("valid");
  } else {
    console.error("invalid");
  }
};
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
input:placeholder-shown, input:focus {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactForm">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required minlength="3" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I want. Thank you!!
Since all the validations are defined in html, I did not want to add event listeners just for applying error style to inputs.

Answer (score 1):

*No javascript needed!*

You can achieve this effect with **CSS alone** by combining a ***zero-length*** placeholder attribute:

- `placeholder=""`

with the *placeholder-shown* pseudo-class:

- `:placeholder-shown`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

input:invalid:placeholder-shown {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<label for="field-1">Field 1:</label>
<input type="text" name="field-1" id="field-1" placeholder="" pattern=".{3,}" required />

<label for="field-2">Field 2:</label>
<input type="text" name="field-2" id="field-2" placeholder="" pattern=".{3,}" required />

<label for="field-3">Field 3:</label>
<input type="text" name="field-3" id="field-3" placeholder="" pattern=".{3,}" required />
```

---

**Further Reading**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to change the `bgcolor` when the input is invalid. See the below code snippet.

```js
const contactForm = document.forms.contactForm;
const nameInp = contactForm.name;

nameInp.onblur = function () {
  if (this.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("valid");
    this.style.background="white"
  } else {
    console.error("invalid");
    this.style.background="tomato"
  }
};
```

```css
input{
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="contactForm">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required minlength="3" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or simply use `onkeyup` that will make the changes instantly

Answer (score 0):

OP problem:

> *The problem with this is that all input fields show up in red even when the user has not touched the field.
> Is it possible to achieve this functionality without javascript using only pseudo classes? I do not want the input boxes to display on red until user clicks on them.*

Add the following after the `input:invalid {}`

> ```
> input:not(:focus) {
>   background-color: white;
> }
>
> input:placeholder-shown {
>    background-color: white;
> }
> ```

Add `placeholder= ' '` to each `<input>`

It's the behavior you described with no JavaScript, just CSS.

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

input:not(:focus) {
  background-color: white;
}

input:placeholder-shown {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactForm">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=' ' required minlength="3" /><br>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder=' ' required><br>

    <label>Lucky Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" placeholder=' ' required min='0' max='999'>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```