# Validating a form per step in pure JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a multiple step form, divided by `.step-box`. I don't want the user to get to the next step when fields are left empty. So that when you click on `.next`, that the form will show which fields are still required. I can access all inputs,selects,radios and checkboxes via `stepBoxes[stepIndex].querySelectorAll('input, select')`.

```
const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.next-btn');
const stepBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.step-box');
const backBtn = document.querySelector('.back-btn');
const stepCircles = document.querySelectorAll('.step-circle');
let stepIndex = 0;

nextBtns?.forEach((nextBtn) => {
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        stepBoxes[stepIndex].classList.add('hide');
        let inputs = stepBoxes[stepIndex].querySelectorAll('input, select');
        
        stepCircles[stepIndex].classList.remove('active');
        stepIndex++;
        stepBoxes[stepIndex].classList.remove('hide');
        stepCircles[stepIndex].classList.add('active');
        backBtn.classList.toggle("hide", stepIndex == 0);
    });
});
```

I tried looping through the fields per step which kinda worked out with a select and a regular text input field. just by looping through them and adding an `.invalid` class to the ones which are required. It worked out for the regular inputs and select boxes, but not for the radios/checkboxes. Since you've got multiple per item.

I was wondering if someone had a vanilla JS idea on how to do this in a proper way.

Specific text inputs, select boxes and radio groups need to be required. For checkboxes I don't really mind since those are optional.

EDIT:

I currently created a specific form per step, where I added the required attribute to the required fields.

```
const membershipForm = document.getElementById('membershipForm');

membershipForm?.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(membershipForm);
    for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
        jsonObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    console.log(jsonObject);
});
```

Comment: Why not make the fields "required" ? then no JS needed. Make sure the select's first option is value="". [Here is how to make radios required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field)

Comment: @mplungjan that only option would work when you click on the actual submit button in the end right? Cause I don't want users to get to the next step, when required fields are still empty

Comment: Make each step a form and gather the values in an array and have the last submit ajax the results

Comment: @mplungjan that sounds do-able. And easy, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @mplungjan I currently trying it with the first step https://pastebin.com/Q0zH7baq Although nothing seems to be logging in the console.

Comment: You can click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor here at SO - I do not see a running version in the pastebin

Comment: Please make a [mcve] here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example

I assume you can figure out to add a `prev`

```js
const result = [];
const formDiv = document.getElementById('forms');
const forms = formDiv.querySelectorAll('form');
let currentForm = 0;
formDiv.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const tgt = e.target;
  const formData = new FormData(tgt);
  result[currentForm] = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(result);
  currentForm++;
  if (currentForm===forms.length) {
    console.log("submit",result)
    return
  }
  let nextForm = forms[currentForm];
  tgt.hidden = true;
  nextForm.hidden = false;  
});
```

```html
<div id="forms">
  <form id="form1" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Field1" value="" required />
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" required>Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no">No</label>
    <input type="submit" value="next"/>
  </form>
  <form id="form2" class="form" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Field2" value="" required />
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="yes" required>Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="no">No</label>
    <input type="submit" value="next" />
  </form>
  <form id="form3" class="form" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Field3" value="" required />
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio3" value="yes" required>Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio3" value="no">No</label>
    <input type="submit" value="next" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly how I am doing it now. although I use the hide form way a bit like my old way, which fits in fine. I did not know that `hidden` was a form attribute. But you're way worked!

Comment: Since I'm using the basic html/js validation way, is it easy to add an `.invalid` class to to empty required fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233435/check-validity-and-apply-style-when-user-leaves-the-field

Comment: that does work, but already applies the invalid styling to it when the form loads

Comment: Have a play around with this - I do not have time right now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021801/inputinvalid-css-rule-is-applied-on-page-load